# Docker-compose Nodejs Mongodb doesn't success

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am testing `NodeJS + MongoDB` on local Mac OS with `docker-compose`, but `NodeJS` and `MongoDB` can't connect successfully.

---

**If I didn't setup `--auth` for `MongoDB` by below code, all works well.**

Here's the code:

**mongoose connection**

`mongodb://mongodb:27017/myprojectdatabase`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    volumes:
     - .:/mycode
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

---

**Then I want to start `--auth` for the MongoDB like below, I got errors.**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    volumes:
     - .:/mycode
    # environment:
    #  - NODE_ENV=production
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: [--auth]
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: my_admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: my2019
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: myprojectdatabase
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./mydata:/data/db
```

Then I run

```
docker-compose down -v && docker-compose up --build
```

I got the output:

```
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.847+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=9554854909b1
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.4
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.869+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true }, security: { authorization: "enabled" } }
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.873+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.876+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.878+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:54:09.879+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=487M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),    
web_1      | connection error: { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.160.2:27017]
    web_1      |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:505:11)
    web_1      |     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

And some times I can see the log contains the user created information, sometimes are not.

```
 2019-03-01T10:38:50.323+0000 I STORAGE  [conn2] createCollection: admin.system.users with generated UUID: 6b3b88f9-e77c-4094-a1c7-153816202a9e
mongodb_1  | Successfully added user: {
mongodb_1  |    "user" : "my_admin",
mongodb_1  |    "roles" : [
mongodb_1  |        {
mongodb_1  |            "role" : "root",
mongodb_1  |            "db" : "admin"
mongodb_1  |        }
mongodb_1  |    ]
mongodb_1  | }
mongodb_1  | 2019-03-01T10:38:50.340+0000 E -        [main] Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed: Unable to open() file /home/mongodb/.dbshell: Unknown error
```

I am new on docker stuff. I guess the main problem is `web` can't establish a connection with `mongodb`. Spend too long on this problem.

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not going to localhost of the web container. Treat containers as separate machines: localhost in one container is not shared with another one. That's why in the connection string you have `mongodb:27017` and not `localhost:27017`, because `mongodb` in your default docker network is a DNS name of the container with mongo. You are using this connection string in the first (successful) case, make sure you have a valid DNS name in the second one.

And also make sure to include your DB credentials (username:password) in the connection string too.